# How to get the values of html hidden wrapped by a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden-field

Im very new to javascript and jquery so please bear with me.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/94MnY/1/

Im trying to get the values of each hidden field inside the div.

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input#btnDispHidden').click(function() {
   var totalHidden = 7;

   for(var i=0; i<totalHidden; i++) {
    alert($("#hiddenField hidden").html());
   }
 });
});
```

but the value Im getting is `null`.

I also wanna know how to get the total number of html elements inside a div. In my case how am I gonna get the total number hidden field inside the div. I assigned the value of `totalHidden` = 7 but what if I dont know total number of hidden fields.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just create an array of those hidden elements using query and loop through them and alert their values.

I have put a jsfiddle for you to see

http://jsfiddle.net/94MnY/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input#btnDispHidden').click(function() {
                $("#hiddenField input[type='hidden']").each(function(i, e){
                    alert($(this).val());
                });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

`$('#hiddenField hidden')` is attempting to access an actual `<hidden>` tag that is a child of `#hiddenField`

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/94MnY/5/) instead. What you want to use is the `input[type=hidden]` selector syntax. You can then loop through each of the resulting input fields using the `jQuery.each()` method.

Comment: +1 to having a concise answer with an example before anyone else

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate over the `<input>` elements and `alert` each value try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#btnDispHidden').click(function() {
    $('#hiddenField input').each(function() {
       alert(this.value);
    });
  }); 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94MnY/8/

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/94MnY/7/) it is.

Basically, you are looking for .each(). I removed a few input fields because so many alert messages are annoying. Also added in the selector the type hidden to avoid getting your last input field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input#btnDispHidden').click(function() {
            $('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(i){
                alert($(this).attr('value'))        
            })
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To stick to what you already have - but with few modifications:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/94MnY/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input#btnDispHidden').click(function() {
            var totalHidden = $('#hiddenField input[type=hidden]').length; // get number of inputs

            for(var i=0; i<totalHidden; i++) {
                alert($("#hiddenField input[type=hidden]").eq(i).val());
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#hiddenfield input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
   alert(this.val());
});
```